# WSL: The file cannot be accessed by the system

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using WSL2 (Windows Subsystem for Linux) which was working fine. After a system restore, it is not connecting and shows the error message

> The file cannot be accessed by the system

I am using Ubuntu as Linux distribution.

[image: Error I get from terminal]

Does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  Please see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11810933) for the many reasons we ask that you not post text as an image.  You should be able to copy/paste the error here.  Thanks!

Comment: WHAT file cannot be accessed? This info may be interesting.

Answer (score 1):

This usually means that WSL is unable to load the virtual disk (`ext4.vhdx`) for Ubuntu from the expected location.

To determine where it is looking, run the following command from PowerShell as your regular user:

```
Get-ChildItem HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Lxss\ |
    ForEach-Object {
        (Get-ItemProperty $_.PSPATH) | Select-Object DistributionName,BasePath
    }
```

Does this path exist on your system after the restore? Unfortunately, it's possible that the [System Restore reset your local `AppData`](https://superuser.com/q/1651316/1210833).  Could the Restore Point have been created before the Ubuntu distribution?

If you can find the `ext4.vhdx`, then it should be possible to restore the session by simply copying the file back into the directory that is returned above.

If you aren't concerned about the data and only want to "reset" Ubuntu back to a working state, you can do this with:

```
wsl --unregister Ubuntu
ubuntu.exe
```

Normally here I'd warn you that `wsl --unregister` is a destructive operation and will remove the virtual disk associated with WSL, in this case you don't have one anyway.